# How to properly update a forked masternode coin

Tags: dash

I have a BitcoinCore/Dash Fork I've gotten to run successfully.  I have it mining correctly in the Wallet, also have 1 Full node, and 2 master nodes setup.  All have been working perfectly fine, I ended up mining up past 1000 block.  The problem I am running into mentally is how do I properly update the core code and push out updates without disrupting the whole network?  How does the network know that my node I push code to, is the correct one it should be receiving updates from?

Also, is my first "full node" (which is just a node, not an actual masternode) ever goes down, does the network still continue forward?  When I bring my full node backonline with new updates does it just resync with the other nodes for the blockchain?

The reason why I ask this is because I just tried to do an update and I had taken down my 2 masternodes and my full node, plus my QT wallet, then when I went to update everything and get back online everything got stuck in a "out of sync" since 4 hours had past.

Comment: Not sure I understand the downvotes, this is a legitimate concern for any new blockchain developer that is just trying to understand how everything works